# scrollTop offset resetting to zero every other time script is run

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

My script only scrolls the text to the correct spot in the modal every other time I run it. I'm including a screen to show how the console is logging a '0' every other time I run the function.

Excerpt:

```
var offset = $('span').parent().offset().top-230; 
console.log(offset);
$('.modal-body').animate({scrollTop: offset}, 'fast');
```

EDIT: Adding whole script

```
$('.opBlurb span a').on('click', function() {
        var givenString = $(this).text();
        $('#opModal').modal({
              show: true,
              open: setTimeout(function() {
                    var matches = $('.modal-body p').
                            addBack().
                            contents().
                            filter(function(){                     
                                return this.nodeType === 3;
                            }).
                            filter(function(){
                            // Only match when contains given string anywhere in the text               
                                 if(this.nodeValue.indexOf(givenString) != -1)
                                   return true;
                      }).first();

                if(matches.length > 0){
                    var offset = $(matches).wrap('<span>').parent().offset().top-230; 
                    console.log(offset);
                    $('.modal-body').animate({scrollTop: offset}, 'fast');
                }
            },500)}
        );
    });
```

[image: Console:]

Comment: is `$('span').parent()` always visible?

Comment: Obviously, something is happening outside of the 3 lines you provided.  You might want to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I could include the whole script (another 20 lines or so, but I get chided for "too much additional code."  @Kilmazing Yes, it's always visible.

Comment: I'm actually having two issues.  I'm wanting to also just `wrap()` the filtered matching string inside of `.modal-body p` instead of wrapping the whole `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

The offset needed to be incremented.

`$('.modal-body').animate({scrollTop: offset}, 'fast');`

should read

`$('.modal-body').animate({scrollTop: '+='+offset}, 'fast');`

Now it scrolls to the right place each time.